# How do I run my Chrome extension once on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that's currently opening up a side-menu when clicked. That works alright so far, but I'm trying to bind it to a key. That works fine, but only after I've clicked the button at least once, since that's when it injects the JS from the background JS page

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(clicked)`

Calls:

```
var opened = [];

function clicked(tab){
    var currentTabId = tab.id;
    if(opened.indexOf(currentTabId) < 0){
        opened.push(currentTabId);

        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'jquery.js'
        });
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
            file: 'admin.css'
        });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'admin.js'
        });
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'admin.toggle();'
        });
    }
}
```

This all works great. `Admin.js` also listens for the tilde `~` button to open up the side-drawer, too (it calls the same `admin.toggle()` function). But the problem is I need to inject the JS before the first button click, so it knows to listen for the `~`.

Can I still do this using a `browserAction`? Or would I need to use a content script instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser action get's triggered when the user clicks the browser-action button. So there is no way (and no point) to trigger it programmatically.

You are already using content scripts (files and code injected by means of `executeScript`) are content scripts (just **[programmatically injected](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)**).

If you want to have the functionality available "right away" you need to inject some content scripts automatically when the user navigates to a new web-page.

One way to achieve this is through the **[`content_scripts` property](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration)** in **manifest.json**.

If you don't want to inject jQuery and `admin.js` in every web-page (especially if your script is "heavy", e.g. registering lots of event-listeners etc), you could inject a tiny script to listen for `~` and only then unregister the listener, inject your scripts and execute `admin.toggle()`.